# Receiving an Web Config Path error in IIS after Migration

Tags: iis

Upon trying to open the "Application Settings" in IIS after a migration, I am receiving the following error:

> Filename: \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your web.config for your web app exists at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\`?

Comment: Thank you Mohsin. Yes it does.